# How to send post request without submit button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have form where I don't have submit button and actually the form didn't send post request, so my question how is possible to send request on image click?

```
@foreach($items as $item)
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('index', $item->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="well"> 
                    <a><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{{ $item->imagePath }}" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="text-center">{{ $item->item_name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
        @endforeach
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with jQuery. It's easy if you set id of the form:

```
$('form#form_id a').click(function(e){
    $('form#form_id').submit();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

But in your case you don't have any point in submitting post request, but anyway the above should work.

Comment: okey, not submitting, I want to send request, but this code doesn't work.

Comment: mean you want to go in controller method without submit? is this your question?

Comment: yes, i want to send the category id in the controller when i click on the image

Comment: You should include input fields with the values:
<input name="category_id" value="{{ $item->id }}"> for example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "Don't use a submit button" is not a hard requirement and you are just assuming that it is because you want to use an image:

Use a submit button instead of a link.

```
<button><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{{ $item->imagePath }}" alt=""></button>
```

You can style the default background and borders of the button away with CSS.

You really should have some content in the `alt` attribute. The image can't be a meaningless decorative image if it informs the user that clicking it will do something.

Answer (score 0):

give id to your form in this way

```
<form action="" id="frm-id" method="post" class="form-horizontal ">
```

next you js method will be as

```
$("#frm-id").submit(function(){
var form_data =  $("#frm-id").serialize();
$.ajax({
            url: '/index/'+id,
            type: "POST",
     });
   });
```

At url above you need to your route to go in controller method as i wrote....